# How screen handling program(eg.vi, less) work?

Tags: linux, signals, vi

Suppose I'm reading a document in vi. When I reach the end of the screen and press the arrow down key, a new screen including the contents of the next line is printed in the terminal.

I wonder how this process is implemented.

Is vi process raise SIGTSTP and call signal handler to continue the process with new screen including next line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is ... process raise SIGTSTP and call signal handler ...

No.

The program first performs a `tcsetattr()` (which internally performs a special `ioctl()`) so the keyboard input is not handled line-wise but key-wise.

Then it prints out 25 lines.

Now it simply uses `read()` to wait for a key pressed.

If you press the `DOWN` key, one additional line is printed.

If you press the `UP` key (in the case of `less`), it is a bit more tricky; depending on the terminal used, some "escape sequence" (a special combination of bytes) is written to the screen using `write()`. This will cause the screen to be scrolled down. Then another "escape sequence" is written which places the cursor to the top left of the screen and one line of text is printed at the top of the screen.

When this is done, the program waits for the next key using `read()` ...

Signals are not involved.